# How do I filter for similar products using checkboxes with PHP, AJAX and JS?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Here is an image of what I'm trying to accomplish - 
[image]

Example of my Database Table - [image]

My goal is to get a similar product to the product that is currently displaying without refreshing the page. I am trying to find similar products is by using check boxes.

I first got the id using $_GET['id'] which should be equal to one of the values in my table.

I then used PDO Fetch to get the product name, brand, quanity and price of that particular id and store it as a string.

What I need help with is using JQuery/AJAX to get the checkboxes that are checked and then send the information to a PHP file that would check if filter results match with any data from the table.

How can I do this?

This is my product.php file

```html
 <?php
    require ('includes/db.php');

    $id = $_GET['id']; //Getting the ID in URL. ex products.php?id=12

    $stmt = $handler->prepare("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = '$id' ");
    $result = $stmt->execute(array());
    $products   = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $prod_name = $products['prod_name']; //Product Name

    $brand = $products['brand']; //Product Brand
    $quantity = $products['quantity']; //Product Quantity
    $calories = $products['calories'];  //Product Calories
    $price = $products['price'];    //Product Price


?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
    <head>
        <title><?php echo "$brand $prod_name"; ?></title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1><?php echo $prod_name; ?></h1>
        <br />

        <p>Brand = <?php echo " $brand"; ?></p>
        <p>Quantity = <?php echo " $quantity"; ?></p>
        <p>Calories = <?php echo " $calories"; ?></p>
        <p>Price = <?php echo " $price"; ?></p>

        <br />

        <p style="text-align: center;">Find Similar Products</p>

        <form> 
        <div class="checkboxes">
            <label>
                <input name="brand" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $brand; ?>">
                <span>Brand</span> <!--Brand Checkbox-->
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkboxes">
            <label>
                <input name="quanitity" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $quantity; ?>">
                <span>Quantity</span> <!--Quantity Checkbox-->
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkboxes">
            <label>
                <input name="calories" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $calories; ?>">
                <span>Calories</span> <!--Calories Checkbox-->
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkboxes">
            <label>
                <input name="price" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $price; ?>">
                <span>Price</span>  <!--Price Checkbox-->
            </label>
        </div>
    </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Study some tutorials on ajax submit of forms that also uses php. Need to narrow down the issues here because you have multiple layers involved ... submit event handling, ajax process both jQuery and php as well as db comparisons. Too broad for one question here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve this out, glad I didn't give up.

My product.php File

```
<?php
require ('/db.php');

$id = $_GET['id']; //Getting the ID in URL. ex products.php?id=12

$stmt = $handler->prepare("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = '$id' ");
$result = $stmt->execute(array());
$products   = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$prod_name = $products['prod_name']; //Product Name

$brand = $products['brand']; //Product Brand
$quantity = $products['quantity']; //Product Quantity
$calories = $products['calories'];  //Product Calories
$price = $products['price'];    //Product Price


?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head>
    <title><?php echo "$brand $prod_name"; ?></title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1><?php echo $prod_name; ?></h1>
    <br />

    <p>Brand = <?php echo " $brand"; ?></p>
    <p>Quantity = <?php echo " $quantity"; ?></p>
    <p>Calories = <?php echo " $calories"; ?></p>
    <p>Price = <?php echo " $price"; ?></p>

    <br />

    <p style="text-align: center;">Find Similar Products</p>

    <form method="post" action=""> 
    <div class="checkboxes">
        <label>
            <input name="brand" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $brand; ?>">
            <span>Brand</span> <!--Brand Checkbox-->
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkboxes">
        <label>
            <input name="quanitity" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $quantity; ?>">
            <span>Quantity</span> <!--Quantity Checkbox-->
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkboxes">
        <label>
            <input name="calories" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $calories; ?>">
            <span>Calories</span> <!--Calories Checkbox-->
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkboxes">
        <label>
            <input name="price" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $price; ?>">
            <span>Price</span>  <!--Price Checkbox-->
        </label>
    </div>
</form>
<div class="filter_container">

    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/filter.js"></script>

<input name="prod_name" value="<?php echo $prod_name ?>" style="display:none;"/>
<!--Hidden product name-->
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my JS File

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function showValues() {


    var brand;  
    var quantity;   
    var calories;       
    var price;      

    //Gets product name
    var prod_name = $('input[name="prod_name"]').val(); 

    //Gets brand
    if($('input[name="brand"]').is(':checked')) 
        {brand = $('input[name="brand"]').val();} else {brand = ""}

    //Gets quantity
    if($('input[name="quantity"]').is(':checked')) 
        {quantity = $('input[name="quantity"]').val();} else {quantity = ""}

    //Gets calories
    if($('input[name="calories"]').is(':checked')) 
        {calories = $('input[name="calories"]').val();} else {calories = ""}

    //Gets price
    if($('input[name="price"]').is(':checked'))  
        {price = $('input[name="price"]').val();} else {price = ""}


        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/query.php",
        data: {'brand':brand, 'quantity':quantity, 'calories':calories, 'prod_name':prod_name}, 
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
            $('.filter_container').html(data)
                }
            });


}

//Call function when checkbox is clicked
$("input[type='checkbox']").on( "click", showValues );

//Remove checked when checkbox is checked
$(".checkboxes").click(function(){
    $(this).removeAttr('checked');      
    showValues();
});
});
```

Here is my PHP File

```
<?php
include('/db.php');

$prod_name = $_POST['prod_name'];

$Cbrand = $_POST['brand'];
$Cquantity = $_POST['quantity'];
$Ccalories = $_POST['calories'];
$Cprice = $_POST['price'];


if(!empty($Cbrand))
{
    $data1 = "brand = '$Cbrand' AND";
}else{
    $data1 = "";
}
if(!empty($Cquantity))
{
    $data2 = "quantity = '$Cquantity' AND";
}else{
    $data2 = "";
}
if(!empty($Ccalories))
{
    $data3 = "calories = '$Ccalories' AND";
}else{
    $data3 = "";
}
if(!empty($Cprice))
{
    $data4 = "price = '$Cprice'";
}else{
    $data4 = "";
}


$main_string = "WHERE $data1 $data2 $data3 $data4"; //All details

$stringAnd = "AND"; //And

$main_string = trim($main_string); //Remove whitespaces from the beginning and end of the main string

$endAnd = substr($main_string, -3); //Gets the AND at the end

if($stringAnd == $endAnd)
{
$main_string = substr($main_string, 0, -3);
}else if($main_string == "WHERE"){
    $main_string = "";
}
else{
    $main_string = "WHERE $data1 $data2 $data3 $data4";
}

if($main_string == ""){ //Doesn't show all the products

}else{

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM products $main_string";

if ($res = $handler->query($sql)) {

/* Check the number of rows that match the SELECT statement */
if ($res->fetchColumn() > 0) {
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM products $main_string";
foreach ($handler->query($sql) as $pro) {

if(($pro['prod_name'] == $prod_name) && ($res->fetchColumn() < 2))
{
    //The product currently being displayed is blank when using the filter
}
else{
    ?>

    <!------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->    

    <div class="form-result">
        <td><?=strtoupper($pro['brand']) + " " + strtoupper($pro['prod_name']); ?></td>
    </div>

    <!------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->


    <?php
}
}
}    /* No rows matched -- do something else */
    else {
        ?>
        <div align="center"><h2 style="font-family:'Arial Black', Gadget, sans-serif;font-size:30px;color:#0099FF;">No Results with this filter</h2></div>
        <?php
        }
    }
}
$handler = null;
$res = null;
?>
```